# Ajax display my whole html each time I do a request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This is a rails app, and I am trying to make dynamique my Gmaps markers...

With the code below my html is repeated each time I do a request...
I am very new with JS and Ajax, please What should I do to make it work?

```
$(function(){

  $('#normal-choice input').on('click', function(event) {
    var url = '/meals?';
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      data: $('.normal-form').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $('.meals-normal').replaceWith($(data).find('.meals-normal').parent().html()),
        $('#map').replaceWith($(data)).find('#map').updateMarkers(markerJson),

        history.replaceState({}, "meals", url);
      },

      error: function(jqXHR) {
        console.error(jqXHR.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

### EDIT

when `$('#map').replaceWith($(data)).find('#map').updateMarkers(markerJson);` is not in the code, the meal are well displayed a reload when filtered
and when I had that line... it messes every thing...

#### here is some more of my code:

this my meals index view

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <section class="choice" id="normal-choice">
        <form action="/meals" method="get" class= "normal-form">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <% @categories.each do |category| %>
              <li>
                <label class="categories">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="<%= category.name %>"
                    <%= "checked" if !params[:categories].nil? && params[:categories].include?(category.name) %>>

                  <span>
                     <span class="icons text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     </span>
                    <%= category.name %>
                  </span>

                </label>
              </li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
          <input class="valid-btn" type="submit" value="Filtrer">
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>

  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <section class="meals-normal">
      <% if @meals_count != 0 %>
        <div class="row">
          <% @meals.sort.each do |meal| %>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
              <%= link_to meal_path(meal) do %>
              <div class="card-meal">
                <div class="description text-center">
                  <div class="description-meal">
                    <h3><%= meal.menu_name  %></h3>
                    <span><small><%= meal.category.name %></small></span>
                    <br>
                    <% if  meal.images?%>

                      <%= cl_image_tag meal.images.first.path, width: 200, height: 100, crop: :fill %>

                    <% end %>
                    <h4>Cuisiné par: <%= meal.user.nickname %></h4>
                    <p>Prévu pour le: <%= meal.availability %></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price-icons">
                    <p> <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(meal.price) %></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>

      <% else %>
        <p class="no-meal">Aucun repas ne correspond à votre recherche.

         <%= link_to 'Effacer les filtres', meals_path('category[]' => 'all') %>
         </p>
      <% end %>

    </section>
  </div>

  </div>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;" data-markers='<%= raw @markers_hash.to_json %>'></div>

</div>
```

and this is my map.js

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');

$(document).on('ready', function() {
  if ($('#map').length > 0) {
    var markerJson = $('#map').data('markers');
    drawMeAMap(markerJson);
  }
});

function drawMeAMap(markerJson){
  $('#map').html('');
  handler.buildMap(
    {
      internal: { id: 'map' }

    },
    addMarkers(markerJson),
  );
};

function updateMarkers(markerJson){
  removeMarkers(markerJson);
  addMarkers(markerJson);

};

function removeMarkers(markerJson){
  handler.buildMap({ internal: { id: 'map' } }, function() {
    markers = handler.removeMarkers(markerJson);
    });
};

function addMarkers(markerJson){
  handler.buildMap({ internal: { id: 'map' } }, function() {
    markers = handler.addMarkers(markerJson);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    if (markers.length == 0) {
      handler.getMap().setZoom(2);
    } else if (markers.length == 1) {
      handler.getMap().setZoom(14);
    }
  });
};
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Without knowing what "data" contains it's hard to help. Nevertheless: https://jsfiddle.net/q7920mvj/ does this help?

Comment: @newBee I edited for the data, and no sorry jsfidle did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

I would try to answer from different way for your current answer

#### 1. create routes for your ajax,

- It depend with what you want to achieve, if you like to show data then data you create route with get
- if you want to get input from user then you create route with post below is sample code for get and post

  ```
  resources :some_resources do
  collection {
      get  :get_data 
  }
  end
  resources :some_resources do
  collection {
      post :accept_data  
  }
  ```

  end

#### 2.use controller to get the data

- Below sample of controller

  ```
  def get_data
     # here you search data to show
  end
  ```

#### 3. create link to call the ajax

- the key to use ajax in rails is using keyword remote: true ([reference: working with javascript](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html))

  `<%= link_to 'show data', get_data_some_resources_path, remote: true %>`

#### 4. Create view with js format

- since we using remote: true, rails will automatically render **get_data.erb.js** usually without remote: true rails will just render get_data.erb.html (make sure you put this file inside /app/views/some_resources/ folder.
- put your js code here to show the data.
- usually I'm using bootstrap modal to show the data with this code below

  ```
  // Render the new form
  $('.modal-body').html('<%= j render("pop-up-form.html.erb") %>');
  // Show the dynamic dialog
  $('#dialog').modal("show");
  ```

Comment: That would made me change most of my code... I am sure there is a little thing I missed....